# ASP.NET Webforms Web project not recognizing references

Tags: asp.net, webforms, reference

I have opened my Solution after few weeks. The code was ok before....
Upon building, i realized that most of my references are not recognize anymore.

I tried cleaning solution, rebuilding all projects, and nothing. It seems strange that only my web project is missing these references. I have some library and simple console app.

I assume there is some way to restore these references, but i could not find any direct method how to do it.[image: Some references have this yellow triangle i can do nothing about.]

Is there any way to restore these references, or should I just create new web project and copy everything?

Comment: Right-click Solution Explorer and choose “Restore NuGet packages”.

Comment: [Right-click *Solution* in Solution Explorer.]